# Need pivot query for my table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a following table called user_var

```
User_ID     VAR_ID  VALUE   START_DATE      END_DATE
1           25      2.0     01-JAN-2009     31-DEC-2011
1           56      4.56    01-JAN-2009     31-DEC-2011
1           89      7.8     01-JAN-2009     31-DEC-2011
2           25      5.64    01-OCT-2009     30-SEPT-2012
2           56      4.86    01-OCT-2009     30-SEPT-2012
2           89      9.87    01-OCT-2009     30-SEPT-2012
1           25      6.33    01-JUL-2009     30-JUN-2012
1           56      4.78    01-JUL-2009     30-JUN-2012
1           89      1.2     01-JUL-2009     30-JUN-2012
2           25      7.21    01-JAN-2009     31-DEC-2011
2           56      2.33    01-JAN-2009     31-DEC-2011
2           89      1.65    01-JAN-2009     31-DEC-2011
1           25      7.89    01-APR-2009     31-MAR-2012
1           56      0.00    01-APR-2009     31-MAR-2012
1           89      1.78    01-APR-2009     31-MAR-2012
2           25      7.6     01-JUL-2009     30-JUN-2012
2           56      7.15    01-JUL-2009     30-JUN-2012
2           89      8.54    01-JUL-2009     30-JUN-2012
```

I want to pivot table on the basis of VAR_ID over the time interval 
suppose VAR_ID 25 stands for Credit
VAR_ID  56 stands for Debit
and VAR_ID  89 stands for Balance

output should be

```
USER_ID     CREDIT      DEBIT   BALANCE     START_DATE      END_DATE
1           2.0         4.56    7.8         01-JAN-2009     31-DEC-2011
2           5.64        4.86    9.87        01-OCT-2009     30-SEPT-2012
1           6.33        4.78    1.2         01-JUL-2009     30-JUN-2012
2           7.21        2.33    1.65        01-JAN-2009     31-DEC-2011
1           7.89        0.00    1.78        01-APR-2009     31-MAR-2012
2           7.6         7.15    8.54        01-JUL-2009     30-JUN-2012
```

Comment: Please show us your query so far, and edit your question tags.  It can't be both mysql and oracle.

Comment: So, your groups are identified by (user_id, start_date, end_date)? This is a bit unusual because your time intervals overlap, even for the same user. Is there (or does there need to be) a secondary ID, to tell those time intervals apart? What if user_id 1 had two credits and two debits for an identical time period - how do you tell them apart? (Or do you add them together - but then, why? Not much sense when you have overlapping intervals).

Comment: @mathguy- No I am no summing anything. A user will have only a single set of values for credit, debit and balance in a particular time interval.
The time interval will not be repeated for that user for the same VAR_ID i.e. for credit, debit or balance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Conditional Aggregation**

```
SELECT
   u.user_id
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN var_id = 25 THEN u.Value END) AS Credit
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN var_id = 56 THEN u.Value END) AS Debit
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN var_id = 89 THEN u.Value END) AS Balance
   ,Start_Date
   ,End_Date
FROM
  user_var u
GROUP BY
   u.user_id
   ,start_date
   ,end_date
```